# What is the postgresql equivalent of return in tsql in Stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql

What is the postgresql equivalent of return in tsql in Stored procedure?

```
tsql sample:
    if  ....   
    begin   
        ....    
        return   
    end
```

Comment: [Returning from a Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE)

Comment: Do you really want a [PROCEDURE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) or a [FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)? You can `return` from a  function.

Comment: the stored procedure in tsql, "return" used for exiting procedure. @AdrianKlaver. As far as im concerned, i can use return in order to exit procedure from the link a_horse_with_name sent.